# Can't receive any out-organization emails to activate student license. IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm filling out the form for a free Educational License but my school email doesn't receive any out-organization emails.

when I fill it in as well there is a green screen that says that is compatible with my school and I need to check the mailbox. I don't have access to see out-organization emails.
What can I do about this issue?

And our school (high school) does not give us any student cards.

I trying to talk to my admin and tell them that I need to open the email for out-organization email. he didn't aprrove it.